# Print minimum and maximum for each identity

Tags: awk, grep, max, min, dataframe

I have a list of genes with their starts and ends. There are often different isoforms of these genes, and so I want to create a new file with the minimum start value and the maximum end value.

So:

Input:

```
Chromosome  Start position (bp) Stop position (bp)  Gene name
1   67000041    67208778    SGIP1
1   48999844    50489468    AGBL4
1   16767256    16785385    NECAP2
1   25072044    25167428    CLIC4 
1   33547850    33585783    ADC
1   16767256    16785385    NECAP2
1   16767256    16785491    NECAP2
1   8384389     8404073     SLC45A1
1   92149295    92327088    TGFBR3
1   100661810   100715376   DBT
1   92149295    92327088    TGFBR3
1   92149295    92327088    TGFBR3
1   92351836    92351836    TGFBR3
1   226420201   226496888   LIN9
1   226420000   226485422   LIN9
1   226420201   226496888   LIN9
```

Desired output:

```
Chromosome  Start position (bp) Stop position (bp)  Gene name
1   67000041    67208778    SGIP1
1   48999844    50489468    AGBL4
1   16767256    16785491    NECAP2
1   25072044    25167428    CLIC4
1   33547850    33585783    ADC
1   8384389     8404073     SLC45A1
1   92149295    92351836    TGFBR3
1   100661810   100715376   DBT
1   226420000   226496888   LIN9
```

Essentially, I want to take each gene separately and get MIN{Start position (bp)} and MAX {Stop position (bp)}.

Is there a grep/awk trick to do this? I'll even take an Excel trick if necessary!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may work for you :

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next}
{s[$4]=!s[$4]||$2<s[$4]?$2:s[$4];e[$4]=!e[$4]||$3>e[$4]?$3:e[$4]}
END{for(x in s)print "1", s[x],e[x],x}' file
```

with your file:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==1{print;next}
{s[$4]=!s[$4]||$2<s[$4]?$2:s[$4];e[$4]=!e[$4]||$3>e[$4]?$3:e[$4]}
END{for(x in s)print "1", s[x],e[x],x}' f
Chromosome  Start position (bp) Stop position (bp)  Gene name
1 67000041 67208778 SGIP1
1 226420000 226496888 LIN9
1 8384389 8404073 SLC45A1
1 33547850 33585783 ADC
1 25072044 25167428 CLIC4
1 48999844 50489468 AGBL4
1 16767256 16785491 NECAP2
1 100661810 100715376 DBT
1 92149295 92351836 TGFBR3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR==1 {print; next}
    {
        key = $1 OFS $2
        if (!(key in min)) {
            min[key]=$3; max[key]=$4
        } else {
            if ($3 < min[key]) min[key]=$3
            if ($4 > max[key]) max[key]=$4
        }
    }
    END {
        for (key in min) 
            print key, min[key], max[key]
    }
'
```

```
Chromosome  Start position (bp) Stop position (bp)  Gene name
1   48999844    50489468    AGBL4
1   92149295    92327088    TGFBR3
1   16767256    16785385    NECAP2
1   226420201   226496888   LIN9
1   25072044    25167428    CLIC4
1   226420000   226485422   LIN9
1   8384389 8404073 SLC45A1
1   33547850    33585783    ADC
1   92351836    92351836    TGFBR3
1   100661810   100715376   DBT
1   67000041    67208778    SGIP1
```